# clang -fsanitize=address can't find libclang_rt.asan

Tags: linux, clang, address-sanitizer

It was my first time building `clang` from source, so maybe I messed it up, but if I try to compile a "hello world" with `-fsanitize=address`, I get an error:

```
$ clang -fsanitize=address hello.c 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/local/lib/clang/15.0.7/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan_static-x86_64.a: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/local/lib/clang/15.0.7/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.a: No such file or directory
clang-15: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In fact, `/usr/local/lib/clang/15.0.7/lib` doesn't exist at all (only `include/` there). Did I build `clang` incorrectly? These are the commands I used, on Debian Stable:

```
wget "https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-15.0.7/llvm-project-15.0.7.src.tar.xz"
tar xvf llvm-project-15.0.7.src.tar.xz
cd llvm-project-15.0.7.src
cmake -S llvm -B build -G Ninja -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
ninja -C build check-llvm
sudo ninja -C build install
```

Comment: You did not build the sanitizers. Please see https://compiler-rt.llvm.org/ for instructions.

Comment: @n.m. or to be more specific he did not build the sanitizers _runtime libraries_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments helped. I'm going to leave an answer in case someone else has this problem and finds this post by googling.

The solution is to add `-DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES=all` to the `cmake` command. For example, the complete build instructions can be

```
tar xvf llvm-project-15.0.7.src.tar.xz
cd llvm-project-15.0.7.src
cmake -S llvm -B build -G Ninja -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES=all
ninja -C build check-llvm  
sudo ninja -C build install
```